# How to set up Scrapy and make it crawl one by one?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

How to set up Scrapy and make it crawl one by one?First of all, look at my code below:

```
def parse(self, response):
        movies = Movie.query.filter(Movie.rating_num>6).all()
        for m in movies:
            url = "http://movie.douban.com/subject/"+str(m.id)+"/comments?sort=time&status=P"
            yield Request(url, self.parse_comment)
```

when I ran this spider,it crawed more than one urls in the same moment.In fact,the site i gona crawl defenses this way.So I wanna know if there is a setting to set scrapy to craw urls one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`CONCURRENT_REQUEST`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) and [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain) both to 1 in your settings.